# Java Why Scanner doesn't recognise user input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

I wrote a function to receive user input. Can't get the correct answer back. Always Failure. I am losing my mind right now.

```java
public String getChoice() {
    Scanner SC = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.print("Ready to play? (Y/N) ");
    String playChoice = SC.next();    // Input Y or N
    playChoice = playChoice.replace("\n", "");
    System.out.println("Input length is: " + playChoice.length());
    System.out.println(playChoice);
    if (playChoice == "N") {
        SC.close();
        return "Success N";
    }
    else if (playChoice == "Y") {
        SC.close();
        return "Success Y";
    }
    SC.close();
    return "Failure"; // Always this one works
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 public String getChoice() {
        Scanner SC = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Ready to play? (Y/N) ");
        String playChoice = SC.next();    // Input Y or N
        playChoice = playChoice.replace("\n", "");
        if (playChoice.equals("N")) { // Replace operator '==' with 'equals()' method.
            SC.close();
            return "Success N";
        } else if (playChoice.equals("Y")) { // Same here.
            SC.close();
            return "Success Y";
        }
        SC.close();
        return "Failure"; // Always this one works
    }
```

The reason why your code is not working as intended, is that the `==` **operator** compares whether the 2 compared **object references** are **pointing to the same object**. This obviously is not the case in your **if-statements**, and therefore those expressions will always evaluate to `false`.

the `equals()` method on the other hand actually compares the **content** of the given objects , thus delivering the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

@Bialomazur gave an explanation already and here is a bit cleaner code and tips.

Actually, closing Scanner is not a good practice, but if you decided to, you can close it before your ifs just in one place, since you are not using scanner anymore.
Also, switch looks better here

```
public String getChoice() {
    Scanner SC = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Ready to play? (Y/N) ");
    String playChoice = SC.next();    // Input Y or N
    playChoice = playChoice.replace("\n", "");
    System.out.println("Input length is: " + playChoice.length());
    System.out.println(playChoice);
    SC.close();
    switch (playChoice) {
        case "Y":
            return "Success Y";
        case "N":
            return "Success N";
        default:
            return "Failure";
    }
}
```